# Is there a diffForHumans() in Symfony

Tags: symfony

Is there a diffForHumans() function in symfony framework at like laravel.

```
$forumPost->created_at->diffForHumans();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Carbon php extension and you can install it using composer:

[Carbon php extension](http://carbon.nesbot.com/#gettingstarted)

and here is the link for [diffForHumans()](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff)

Comment: Thank you seifeddine Besbes :)

Comment: any time, hope it helps  ;)